# Background video not playing on Chrome on Android

Tags: android, video, mobile, background

The video doesn't play on Chrome on Android.
I haven't been able to find a solution :(

```
<video id="video" class="video" preload="metadata" autoplay muted loop playsinline>
       <!-- for safari - HEVC format -->
       <source src="images/hero-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <!-- for Chrome - H264 format -->
       <source src="images/hero-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">

       <source src="images/hero-video.webm" type="video/webm">
       <source src="images/hero-video.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```